# jQuery - slice() function starts counting from 1 instead of 0 on Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slice, microsoft-edge

Today I've noticed some strange issues on site i'm creating.
I'm using `slice()` function to get link basing on some attributes.

It works perfect on Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari, but seems to have hard times on Microsoft Edge for some reason?

On modern browsers the `sliced()` links are displayed as follows:

`http://www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/wp-content/themes/BeCreative_ELPLAST/assets/img/docisk-dwustronny.jpg`

while on Microsoft Edge with the very same script it becomes:

`ttp://www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/wp-content/themes/BeCreative_ELPLAST/assets/img/docisk-dwustronny.jp`

meaning additional one letter on both beginning and ending are cut off.

Has anyone also experienced such problem? Any ideas to solve it?

EDIT:

**jQuery:**

```
 $(".zoom").click(function() {
    $bgimg = $(this).parent().parent().parent().css("background-image");
    $bgimgcut = $bgimg.slice(5,-2);
    $img = "<img src='" + $bgimgcut + "' width='100%'/>";
    $(".popup-image").html($img);
    $(".popup").fadeIn();
  });
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @Phil jQuery code added, if anything else is needed let me know

Comment: [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1) returns a string so you're actually using [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), not jQuery `.slice()`. How about you start by debugging the value of `$bgimg` ~ `console.log('$bgimg', bgimg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, everything other than Edge is returning

```css
url("http://www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/wp-content/themes/BeCreative_ELPLAST/assets/img/docisk-dwustronny.jpg")
```

and Edge is returning the same value without quotes

```css
url(http://www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/wp-content/themes/BeCreative_ELPLAST/assets/img/docisk-dwustronny.jpg)
```

You could confirm this with

```
console.log('$bgimg', $bgimg)
```

---

So, it sounds like your real question is how to extract the image URL from a CSS `url(...)` value, with or without quote characters.

Use a regular expression

```
$bgimgcut = $bgimg.match(/url\("?(.*?)"?\)/)[1]
```

```js
const rx = /url\("?(.*?)"?\)/

const strings = [
  'url("http://www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/wp-content/themes/BeCreative_ELPLAST/assets/img/docisk-dwustronny.jpg")',
  'url(http://www.becreativeagencja.com/elplast-wp/wp-content/themes/BeCreative_ELPLAST/assets/img/docisk-dwustronny.jpg)'
]

strings.forEach(str => {
  console.info('url', str.match(rx)[1])
})
```